# How to set a value of a variable of an object in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on an assignment in which I have to:

1. Create an Employee class with the following attributes/variables:
   name
   age
   department
2. Create a class called Department which will contain a list of employees.

   a. Department class will have a method which will return its employees ordered by age.

   b. Value of Department can be only one of the following:

   - "Accounting"
   - "Marketing"
   - "Human Resources"
   - "Information Systems"

I am having the hardest time trying to figure out how to complete 2b.
Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Employee {
String name; 
int age;
String department;

Employee (String name, int age, String department) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.department = department;

}
int getAge() {
    return age;
}
}

class Department {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Employee>empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    Collections.sort (empList, new Comparator<Employee>() {
        public int compare (Employee e1, Employee e2) {
            return new Integer (e1.getAge()).compareTo(e2.getAge());
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: `" b. Value of Department can be only one of the following: "Accounting" "Marketing" "Human Resources" "Information Systems""` -- use an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) type for this property, not a String. This will force Java to only allow specific items of the type for this variable or parameter.

Comment: For more information, check out [Enum Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: Next time please only give information that is relevant to your question.  The whole bunch of code and most of the description of your assignment has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 15):

You can use enumerations for the same purpose which will restrict you to use only specified values. 
Declare your `Department` enum as follows

```
public enum Department {

    Accounting, Marketting, Human_Resources, Information_Systems

}
```

You `Employee` class can now be

```
public class Employee {
    String name;
    int age;
    Department department;

    Employee(String name, int age, Department department) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.department = department;

    }

    int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

and while creating employee, you can use

```
Employee employee = new Employee("Prasad", 47, Department.Information_Systems);
```

**EDIT** as suggested by **Adrian Shum** and of course because it is a great suggestion.

- The enums are constants thats why its good to be declared in capital letters according to java conventions.
- But we don't want the capital representation of the enums to be seen so we can create enum constructors and pass readable info to it.
- We wil modify enum to include `toString()` method and `constructor` which takes a string argument.

  ```
   public enum Department {

     ACCOUNTING("Accounting"), MARKETTING("Marketting"), HUMAN_RESOURCES(
          "Human Resources"), INFORMATION_SYSTEMS("Information Systems");

     private String deptName;

      Department(String deptName) {
         this.deptName = deptName;
      }

     @Override
     public String toString() {
      return this.deptName;
     }

  }
  ```

So when we are creating an `Employee` object as follows and using it,

```
Employee employee = new Employee("Prasad Kharkar", 47, Department.INFORMATION_SYSTEMS);
System.out.println(employee.getDepartment());
```

We will get a readable string representation as `Information Systems` as it is returned by `toString()` method which is called implicitly by `System.out.println()` statement.
Read the good tutorial about [Enumerations](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/01/why-use-enumerations-in-java/)

Comment: Oh Wow...that makes more sense now. Thank you so much!

Comment: This is an elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: just a suggestion, in Java convention, naming of enum should follow constants, that means, the values should be `ACCOUNTING, MARKETING, HUMAN_RESOURCES, INFORMATION_SYSTEMS`.  You may add a method for the enum to provide a human readable name if you want.