# Getting String value from enum in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have a enum defined like this and I would like to be able to obtain the strings for the individual statuses. How should I write such a method?

I can get the int values of the statuses but would like the option of getting the string values from the ints as well.

```
public enum Status {
    PAUSE(0),
    START(1),
    STOP(2);

    private final int value;

    private Status(int value) {
        this.value = value
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Status s = Status.PAUSE; System.out.println(s.name());

Comment: This answer will help you understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606866/how-to-set-a-value-of-a-variable-of-an-object-in-an-arraylist/17607004#17607004

Comment: you want to get PAUSE from integer 1?

Comment: Instead of defining 0,1,2, you can use `Status.ordinal();`

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle: You should avoid using ordinal(), see Joshua Bloch "Effective Java"

Comment: @GarfieldKlon I agree. I don't (and will never) advise to rely on `ordinal()` because adding a value in the enum will shift every enum's ordinal. I wanted to point out that the OP duplicated the `ordinal()`'s behavior.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6667403/2205307 here look at this. It might help.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

if `status` is of type `Status` enum, `status.name()` will give you its defined name.

Comment: @JoeMaher `toString()` seems to be the preferred way as per the official documentation: "Most programmers should use the toString() method in preference to this one, as the toString method may return a more user-friendly name." (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name())

Comment: @Carsten `status.name()` is appropriate if you want to use it in the code (for accuracy and consistency), `status.toString()` is appropriate if you want to show it to the user (for readability).

Answer (score 50):

You can use `values()` method:

For instance `Status.values()[0]` will return PAUSE in your case, if you print it, `toString()` will be called and "PAUSE" will be printed.

Comment: Right, just to add `Status.values()[0]` would be of type `Status` not `String`.

Answer (score 11):

Use default method name() as given bellows

```
public enum Category {
        ONE("one"),
        TWO ("two"),
        THREE("three");

        private final String name;

        Category(String s) {
            name = s;
        }

    }

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Category.ONE.name());
    }
}
```

Comment: why not overriding toString to return name ??

Comment: Returns what? ONE or one, there is a difference (the enum name or its value)

Comment: How to print "One", "Two", I mean the value String for the enum?

Answer (score 9):

You can add this method to your Status enum:

```
 public static String getStringValueFromInt(int i) {
     for (Status status : Status.values()) {
         if (status.getValue() == i) {
             return status.toString();
         }
     }
     // throw an IllegalArgumentException or return null
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("the given number doesn't match any Status.");
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Status.getStringValueFromInt(1)); // OUTPUT: START
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe enum have a .name() in its API, pretty simple to use like this example:

```
private int security;
public String security(){ return Security.values()[security].name(); }
public void setSecurity(int security){ this.security = security; }

    private enum Security {
            low,
            high
    }
```

With this you can simply call

```
yourObject.security()
```

and it returns high/low as String, in this example

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom values() method:

public enum SortType
{
Scored, Lasted;

```
     public int value(){
         return this == Lasted ? 1:0;
     }
}
```