# How to get the Value from Enum in java

Tags: java, enums

How to get the value Apple if I pass A ...

```
public enum Enumtype {
  A("Apple"), B("Ball"), C("Cat");

  private String value;

  private Enumtype(String value) {
      this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: Provide a getter method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741721/getting-string-value-from-enum-in-java

Comment: The same way you get a field in any other object.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a getter in your enum :

```
public String getValue(){
    return this.value;
}
```